# What is the purpose behind the personalized security image often used on banking websites?

Tags: security

Many banking websites have you select your own security image when creating your account.  For subsequent log ins the image is displayed along with a caption, if you do not see the image and caption you chose, you are instructed not to log in.

What is the purpose of this added step, which type of attacks does it protect against?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a [good answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/19801/3542) about the effectiveness of this technique on stack exchange.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer:

[Phishing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing#Augmenting_password_logins).

Long story:

If you receive a fake email instructing you to log in to your bank account following this link: http://i.am.an.cyber.pirate.com/give/me/your/money/paypal/official/site/ultra/secured/website/

And because you don't know about that kind of people, you click on it, but since you don't see your custom image, you **know** that you are not on the official site, because you, and only you should know about this image.

Let's say you choosed a picture of your dog and see your neighboor cat, well, don't log in then.

Comment: Thanks Boris, I understand now.  I'd like to add this seems to be why banks have you enter your username on one page, then retrieve and display your image before prompting you for your password.  That way if you are at a phishing site they only would get your username before you realize it's not legit.

Comment: Why can't an attacker MITM the website and request the image on your behalf?

Comment: @StephenTouset, it could theoretically be feasible, however, most of the time, phishing doesn't target a specific user but try to gather the more users to fetch their personal data. Note that if a man in the middle is able to do this, I would be more worried about much other things. It's like saying "what if my DNS provider gets compromise and I access the wrong address".

Comment: MITM can be done trivially for multiple users through phishing. `http://realbank.com:/lots/of/padding@evil.com`, then just proxy requests between the user and bank capturing authentication credentials. When the bank sends the authentication image, you forward it to the user.

Comment: Many implementations seem to store the image information in cookies to avoid MITM attacks. They require you to re-identify yourself through more personal questions before presenting you with the image. You could still MITM this by presenting those same questions, but it theoretically would trigger the user that something was wrong more so than an invalid image.

Comment: This seems silly and brittle. Why would I recognize an image meant for recognition is not the one I'm supposed to recognize.

Comment: @dclowd9901 The whole point is for the user to provide an image only they recognize which a phishing site wouldn't be able to replicate without having prior access to the user's account (in which case, the phishing campaign is moot). The user must then be trained to look for his/her login image before submitting the rest of their credentials to the site.

Answer (score 0):

any third party can copy the web page.. and show it to you.. you will end up giving your data because to you nothing will be different on the page
but if they have an image that you initially uploaded no third party hacker would be able to know what image is that and hence wont able to replicate the full page